# Solving for Eigenvectors of an Already Diagonalized Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, classical-mechanics

I'm a bit stuck in solving for the eigenvectors of the following equation.
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2m+M-2k\omega & 0
\\
0 & \dfrac{1}{12}Ml^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}ml^2 - \dfrac{k}{2}l^2\omega
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
=0
\end{align}

I found the eigenvalues using Mathematica, but finding the Eigenvectors was problematic, so I attempted it by hand. The eigenvalues are:
\begin{align}
\omega_1=\dfrac{3m}{2k} \ \ , \ \ \omega_2 = \dfrac{6m+M}{6k}
\end{align}

In solving for the eigenvector corresponding to $\omega_1$, I get to the following equation.

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
M-m & 0
\\
0 & \dfrac{1}{12}Ml^2 - \dfrac{1}{6}ml^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
=0
\end{align}

I'm totally unsure on how to solve this for the eigenvector. Essentially, my confusion lies in both $a_1$ and $a_2$ equal to zero here, since there are no off-diagonal terms.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $$ D = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{bmatrix},$$ then clearly $[1,0]^T, [0,1]^T$ are eigenvectors belong to $a,b$ respectively.

Comment: @xbh Can you explain this in further detail?

Comment: That claim is pretty obvious by verifying the definition $Dv = \lambda v$.

Comment: @xbh So, my eigenvectors here would be what, exactly? This isn't obvious to me.

Comment: Instead what did you mean by "eigenvectors of the following equation"? Usually we talk about eigenvectors of *matrices, operators*.